# Drop down menu hidden behind div

Tags: html, css

I'm trying to make an drop down menu, and it's not going well. My submenu is hidden behind my wrapper/page/content. I've tried setting an z-index to different elements, also tried giving my menu and submenu giving:

```
z-index: 999999;
```

But nothing works..

Can you guys help?

http://jsfiddle.net/L8Y3K/

Answer (score 12, accepted):

please remove `overflow:hidden;` from header id it will solve your problem

http://jsfiddle.net/L8Y3K/1/

Answer (score 1):

Try Select2 jquery plugin. it works with `overflow: hidden`

http://jsfiddle.net/jEADR/2442/